# BurpSuite not in full size using bspwm

Tags: udev

When I open burpsuitecomunity edition in a bspwm session, burpsuite does not use the full screen space. But when I open burpsuite in a mate xsession it goes allrtight. This is my bspwmrc file:

```
#!/bin/sh
WMNAME LG3D &
pgrep -x sxhkd > /dev/null || sxhkd &

bspc config pointer_modifier mod1

bspc monitor -d I II III IV V VI VII VIII IX X

bspc config border_width         2
bspc config window_gap          12

bspc config split_ratio          0.52
bspc config borderless_monocle   true
bspc config gapless_monocle      true

bspc rule -a Gimp desktop='^8' state=floating follow=on
bspc rule -a Chromium desktop='^2'
bspc rule -a mplayer2 state=floating
bspc rule -a Kupfer.py focus=on
bspc rule -a Screenkey manage=off
bspc rule -a burp-StartBurp: state=floating
~/.config/polybar/./launch.sh

feh --bg-scale /home/joanf/Descargas/venom.jpg
bspc config focus_follows_pointer true
picom --experimental-backends &
bspc config border_width 0
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr &
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved thanks to https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Java#Impersonate_another_window_manager .

You just `$sudo apt install wmname` and then `$wmname LG3D` .

Hope it helps you!